# C# dynamic compilation and "Microsoft.CSharp.dll" error

Tags: c#, dynamic, ironpython, .net-assembly

I'm doing the example that can be found [here](http://urda.cc/blog/2010/09/24/ironpython-and-csharp/).
So I'm trying to run IronPython in a C# script:

Python:

```
def hello(name):
    print "Hello " + name + "! Welcome to IronPython!"
    return

def add(x, y):
    print "%i + %i = %i" % (x, y, (x + y))
    return

def multiply(x, y):
    print "%i * %i = %i" % (x, y, (x * y))
    return
```

C#:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System;

namespace IntroIronPython
{
    class IronPythonMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new ScriptRuntime for IronPython
            Console.WriteLine("Loading IronPython Runtime...");
            ScriptRuntime python = Python.CreateRuntime();

            try
            {
                // Attempt to load the python file
                Console.WriteLine("Loading Python File...");
                // Create a Dynamic Type for our Python File
                dynamic pyfile = python.UseFile("PythonFunctions.py");
                Console.WriteLine("Python File Loaded!");

                Console.WriteLine("Running Python Commands...\n");

                // Call the hello(name) function
                pyfile.hello("Urda");
                …
```

And from here I have this error:
"Dynamic Operation cannot be compiled without "Microsoft.CSharp.dll" assembly reference."
And I seriously don't understand what that is about, what did I forget to add?

In my references I have:
[image: References of my project]

Thx for your help.

Ps: I'm on MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Basically, my mistake was linked to the fact that I added my IronPython assemblies from the wrong platform. 
Verify that:

- Target Framework: 4.0
- Add all the assemblies provided by IronPython in [IronPython-2.7.3]->[Platforms]->[Net40].

Thx to everyone who gave me advices.

Ps:Now, of course, there is another problem… But it's not about that topic anymore.

Comment: Make sure you flag your own answer as the solution so future visitors can see you solved the problem! Also I'm glad you found and chose to use my example :)

Comment: This was my problem as well. I had added my references using the ".NET" tab in Visual Studio C# 2010 Express. I think the original files that appeared may only have been from the `Net35` directory. Be aware of the `Path` in the Add References dialogue box. When I added them from `IronPython 2.7\Platforms\Net40` the build succeeded, and both sets of assemblies now appear on the .Net tab in Add References. (This may have been the case before too, I just didn't notice).

Answer (score 12):

This is what helped me. I am using Xamarian Studio v5.8.1 (build 8) to write a C# program. I just had to right click "References" -> "Edit References" -> started typing "Microsoft" in the search bar -> Checked the box next to "Microsoft.CSharp" -> and clicked "OK".

I just saved and ran the program after that - everything works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.CSharp.dll` contains the dynamic portion of the C# compiler. Any time you use `dynamic` in your code, you need a reference to it. I'm not familiar with MonoDevelop, but you'll probably have to set the target framework to 4.0, and add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` to the project (probably right-click on the project, 'Add Reference', find Microsoft.CSharp).

My guess is that the project you're using was created with a pre-release version of VS, and is missing the proper references.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I have: Framework 4.0, and as you see in the image Microsoft.CSharp is already in my references; that's the reason why I don't understand this error. Microsoft.CSharp is added in the reference and it stills saying that I cannot compile without it… Do you think other assemblies should be also added to make it work?

Comment: Oh, I missed that in the image. I'm not sure what's going on then. It might be a MonoDevelop issue.

Comment: You can find my solution bellow. I think I was adding the wrong assemblies from the from platform. Got no such problems with IronPython 2.7.0 so I switched.