# Problems embedding IronPython in C# (Missing Compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'

Tags: c#, python, .net, dynamic, ironpython

I'm trying to do a simple hello world to test out embedding IronPython within C# but can't seem to resolve this problem..

This is my C# file;

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System.IO;

public class dynamic_demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();

        dynamic test = ipy.UseFile(@"../../Test.py");

        test.Simple();
    }
}
```

And this is the python class;

```
import sys

def Simple():
    print 'Hello from Python'
    print "Call Dir(): "
    print dir()
    print "Print the Path: " 
    print sys.path
```

My target .NET framework is 4.0 and I'm using IronPython 2.6..

I get 2 errors when I run this one is from a file called "CSC";
Error   5   Missing compiler required member

> 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'  C:\Users\Tolga\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\consoleTest\CSC    consoleTest

The other one is from C# file i created

> Error 6   One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression
>   cannot be found. Are you missing a
>   reference?    C:\Users\Tolga\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\consoleTest\Program.cs 17  9   consoleTest

Here's the output from the Build

```
1>------ Build started: Project: consoleTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.6\Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll'
1>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.6\Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll'
1>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.6\Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll'
1>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'
1>CSC : error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'
1>C:\Users\Tolga\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\consoleTest\Program.cs(17,9,17,20): error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`.  This provides the required types for using `dynamic` in C#.

Also, you will likely need to upgrade to IronPython 2.7[.3] or later, as there are some incompatibilities with old releases and the newer .NET frameworks.

Comment: When I click references in my project, I see Microsoft.CSharp in the list

Comment: @TolgaE If you're compiling from the command line, I'd recommend using `MSBuild` with the project, as this will get the references.  If you use CSC, you need to specify the references yourself (it won't read from the project file).

Comment: @ToglaE Otherwise, just build it inside of Visual Studio, and it should work (since that reference exists)

Comment: I'm building it within Visual Studio. I just hit the "Start" button

Comment: @ToglaE Make sure you're targetting .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.0 Full (not client profile) in the build settings.  Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but it's set to 4.0. I tried with 4.5 as well

Comment: I added the build output in the question, in case that helps

Comment: @TolgaE I believe you may need to upgrade to the latest IronPython (2.7.3) as there are likely some incompatibilities with 2.6 and the latest framework.

Comment: Huzzah!!! That worked (I downgraded to 2.6 before for another problem that's not relevant right now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting this same compiler error (Missing compiler required member) running IronPython 2.7.4 and targeting .NET 4.0 Full Profile.

Comment: Solved my issue. Since it solves a different aspect than this answer, I've added a secondary answer and linked to the question which helped to resolve my issue.

Comment: FWIW adding Microsoft.CSharp.dll means var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("Microsoft.CSharp") i.e. drop the dll. Stumped me for a few mins :)

Answer (score 3):

You will also get this error if you've [included references to the wrong target assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422780/1174169). For instance, if you're building against the .Net 4.0 Full profile, you must include the IronPython assemblies from:

```
<install directory>\IronPython 2.7\Platforms\Net40
```

Including assemblies from the `Net35` directory will also result in the missing `RuntimeBinder` error.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question for a still existing issue I've faced this morning using IronPython 2.7.10 in a new project.

The accepted answer can now be improved : instead of manually adding Microsoft.CSharp.dll, I would recommend adding the package "Microsoft.CSharp" from nuget. Portability will be improved (netstandard, net framework, netcore...).