# Use the dynamic keyword/.NET 4.6 feature in Unity

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement GraphQL into Unity3D (version 2017.1.0f3 Personal). I am using .NET 4.6 (Experimental), but despite this, Unity does not support dynamic keyword. Which is odd, since .NET 4.0 it is the part of .NET. Except in Unity. I was googling for some solution how to get it work, but no solutions to the dynamic keyword. The error is this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1980  Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' 
because the compiler required type 
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you 
missing a reference?    skiing-prototype (1)    D:\skiing-prototype 
(1)\Assets\Scripts\GraphQL.cs   62  Active
```

That is the only caveat of using GraphQL C# client. Has anyone tried it yet to get it work? I hadn't found any greater efforts to get it up and running yet.

EDIT:

I am using this client here: https://github.com/bkniffler/graphql-net-client

Also this is an error from visual studio, but in Unity console it shows errors too, will update what exactly momentarily

```
Assets/Scripts/GraphQL.cs(80,16): error CS1980: Dynamic keyword requires 
`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' to be defined. Are you 
missing System.Core.dll assembly reference?
```

this is the unity editor error, which seems to be the same that in visual studio

Comment: Are you referencing the Microsoft.CSharp.dll? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417047/c-sharp-dynamic-compilation-and-microsoft-csharp-dll-error)

Comment: No I don't since under Unity I can't quite pass around any kind of dll from visual studio, just from this plugins folder

Comment: Also because of this

error CS1703: An assembly `Microsoft.CSharp' with the same identity has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references
Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.CSharp.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Microsoft.CSharp.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: What's the Visual Studio version?

Comment: visual studio 2017 community

Comment: Ok final question. Can you check if another 4.6 feature is working? I just want verify this before adding my answer.

Comment: like which feature, if I may ask?

Comment: it does not work at all, unfortunately

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step is to check if Unity recognizes these 2 basic C# 6 features from [MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#null-conditional-operators).

**1**.Try "Index Initializers" feature:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> webErrors = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [404] = "Page not Found",
    [302] = "Page moved, but left a forwarding address.",
    [500] = "The web server can't come out to play today."
};
```

**2**. then "String Interpolation" feature:

```
private string FirstName = "";
private string LastName = "";
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

If they give you error then the problem is **not** just the `dynamic` keyword but a problem that Visual Studio cannot recognize the *.NET* version being set by Unity.

From the comment section your Unity failed to compile the first example.

---

Go through the steps one by one for a possible fix. Do **not** skip of them.

**1**.Go to Edit --> Project Settings --> Player --> Other Settings --> Configuration --> Scripting Runtime Version --> Experimental (.Net 4.6 Equivalent).

**2**.Go to Edit --> Project Settings --> Player --> Other Settings --> Configuration --> Api Compatibility Level --> .NET 4.6

**3**.Restart Unity Editor and Visual Studio. You must restart both.

Test both C# features above. If they work then the `dynamic` keyword should as-well. If they don't then move on to #4.

**4**.Update Visual Studio. This is very important. Update the visual Studio to the latest version/patch.

**5**.If you can't still get both C#6 features above to compile then Re-install both Visual Studio and Unity then perform step *#1* and *#2* again as some files are missing.

**6**.Finally, if you get both C#6 features working but the dynamic keyword is still not working then update from **Unity 2017.1** to [**Unity 2017.2**](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta). This version fixed many .NET issues.

Note that I am using [**Unity 2017.2**](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) with the `dynamic` keyword without any issue. Also, `GraphQL` is working fine.

Comment: What does it mean if the 1 & 2 features you listed above work but dynamic still doesn't?

Comment: I have UNity 2017.2.0b8

Comment: @JDOaktown Was that a question or a comment?

Comment: I had to insert 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
in order for this "Dictionary" declaration to work.

Answer (score 7):

I seem to have found a solution

Navigate to `Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Configuration > API Compatibility Level` and change from `.NET Standard 2.0` to `.NET 4.x`

This immediately removed the compiler error and allowed me to run code using the dynamic keyword.

Let me know if that was useful