# using dynamic keyword with Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm getting the error:

> Missing compiler required member
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create

Here's the thing. I have VS 2015 Community. I did NOT have the Unity plugin for VS and so I was able to add the Microsoft.CSharp.dll reference and the game would run. However, I wasn't able to debug it because I didn't have the Unity plugin for VS. So I went and installed that, but now I get this error. And now when I right click references in my project explorer I have NO option to add references like I could before so I can't add that reference now.

I've looked at this and this is how I got it working when I didn't have the Unity plugin for VS. This doesn't address my issue. How can I add this Microsoft.CSharp.dll reference in my project now that this Unity plugin won't let me?

[Using dynamic keyword in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616562/using-dynamic-keyword-in-unity)

Comment: No, that did NOT answer my question. It didn't work.

Comment: The other features that they test on that answer work, but dynamic doesn't.